# Ingresar registro en una tabla en una fecha determinada

Tags: postgresql

Buen dia, necesito hacer que en una fecha determinada se ingrese un dato de forma automatica, es decir tengo una tabla cuyo registro debe estar 1 año en ella,cuando se cumpla el año se inserte en otra tabla y se elimine de la primera, deberia hacer un trigger luego del insert en la primera tabla, pero nose como hacer para que se programe la insercion en la fecha futura, muchas gracias por su ayuda(Estoy trabajando con postgressql).

Comment: Para precisamente eso se han desarrollado los eventos, que se diferencian de los disparadores o triggers en que los activa el reloj y el calendario, no una inserción, borrado o modificación

Comment: Se usarían juntos con los triggers? Osea que el disparador agende digamos el evento a tal fecha, estuve buscando sobre eventos en postgres y no encontré mucho

Comment: Un disparador y un evento son completamente independientes. Lo que no impide que un evento escriba en una tabla con un disparador que provoque otra acción en la base de datos. Intenta algo y muestra tu código para que podamos ayudarte